# How to convert epoch decimal time to 64 bit binary and back to decimal in C

Tags: c, binary, epoch

I am trying to create a script that will convert decimals to binary based on specified size and then reverse the process, meaning from binary to decimal. So far the script and the output from my point of view (beginner) the script looks correct. I can convert all numbers from decimal to binary and vice versa. I am stack on the last part, that I am trying to convert the epoch time from a 64 bit binary number to decimal. I can not understand where I am going wrong since the rest of the numbers seem to recovered correctly. The source points that I found the scripts that I am using are [Binary to Decimal](http://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/binary-decimal-convert) and [Decimal to Binary](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-convert-decimal-to-binary).

**Update: modified code to short version:**

I have modified the code to simply demonstrate the problem. The code works fine up to 32 bit binary conversion. But since I need to convert up to 64 I do not know how to do that. I noticed that because I used before `int` I reached the maximum limitations 32 bits, so I modified that to `long long int` to reach the 64 bit.

I have provided a sample of simple conversion of decimal as 1 in 32 bit format and 64 that demonstrate the problem. The epoch time is the desired output but I need to verify that the code works before I attempt the conversion.

Sample of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define MAX_CHARACTERS 65

typedef struct rec {
  char transmit[MAX_CHARACTERS];
  char receive[MAX_CHARACTERS];
}RECORD;

char *decimal_to_binary(int n , int num); /* Define function */

char *decimal_to_binary(int n , int num) {

  long long int c, d, count;
  char *pointer;

  count = 0;

  pointer = (char*) malloc( num + 1 );

  if ( pointer == NULL )
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  for ( c = num - 1; c >= 0; c-- ) {

    d = n >> c;

    if ( d & 1 )
      *( pointer + count ) = 1 + '0';
    else
      *( pointer + count ) = 0 + '0';

     count++;
  }
  *( pointer + count ) = '\0';

  return pointer;
}

int binary_decimal(long long int n); /* Define function */

int binary_decimal(long long int n) { /* Function to convert binary to decimal.*/

  int decimal=0, i=0, rem;

  while (n!=0) {

    rem = n%10;
    n/=10;
    decimal += rem*pow(2,i);
    ++i;

  }

  return decimal;

}

int main(void) {

   RECORD *ptr_record;

   ptr_record = (RECORD *) malloc (sizeof(RECORD));

   if (ptr_record == NULL) {
     printf("Out of memmory!\nExit!\n");
     exit(0);
   }

   int LI_d = 1;
   char *LI_b = decimal_to_binary(LI_d,32);

   memset( (*ptr_record).transmit , '\0' , sizeof((*ptr_record).transmit) );
   strncat((*ptr_record).transmit , LI_b , strlen(LI_b) );

   printf("LI: %s\n",(*ptr_record).transmit);

   //transmit and receive

   memset( (*ptr_record).receive , '\0' , sizeof((*ptr_record).receive) );
   strncpy( (*ptr_record).receive , (*ptr_record).transmit , strlen((*ptr_record).transmit) );

   char *LI_rcv_b = strndup( (*ptr_record).receive , 64 );
   int LI_rcv_i = atoi (LI_rcv_b);
   int final_LI = binary_decimal(LI_rcv_i);
   printf("Final_LI: %i\n",final_LI);

   free( ptr_record );

   return 0;

}
```

Sample of output for 32 bit conversion:

```
LI: 00000000000000000000000000000001
Final_LI: 1
```

Sample of output for 64 bit conversion:

```
LI: 0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001
Final_LI: -1
```

Comment: Note: It appears `strncat((*ptr_record).transmit , VN_b , strlen(VN_b));` used incorrectly.    What you want is `strncat((*ptr_record).transmit , VN_b , sizeof ((*ptr_record).transmit ) - 1);`   This will insure the destination is never overrun and as you initialized the buffer with all 0, the last location is always `'\0'`.

Comment: @chux thank you for your comment and valuable feedback. It seems that I was under the wrong impression. I was trying to convert a 32 bit integer with a value of 64 bit. The result was completely wrong. I have updated the question and the code so I hope now it is more easy to follow. Thanks again for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

1. `decimal_to_binary(int n, ...)`: better to use unsigned math

   ```
   //char *decimal_to_binary(int n, int num) {
   char *decimal_to_binary(unsigned long long n, int num) {
     //  long long int c, d, count;
     unsigned long long int d;
     int c, count;
     char *pointer;

     count = 0;
     pointer = malloc(num + 1);  // drop cast
     if (pointer == NULL)
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

     for (c = num - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
       d = n >> c;
       if (d & 1)
         *(pointer + count) = 1 + '0';
       else
         *(pointer + count) = 0 + '0';
       count++;
     }
     *(pointer + count) = '\0';
     return pointer;
   }
   ```
2. Simplify `binary_decimal()`.  Again use unsigned math, drop `pow()`

   ```
   /* Function to convert binary to decimal.*/
   unsigned long binary_decimal(unsigned long long int n) { 
     unsigned long decimal = 0;
     while (n != 0) {
       decimal *= 2;
       decimal += n % 10;
       n /= 10;
     }
     return decimal;
   }
   ```
3. `main()` has lots of issues

   ```
   int main(void) {
     RECORD *ptr_record;

     ptr_record = malloc(sizeof(RECORD));  // drop cast
     if (ptr_record == NULL) {
       printf("Out of memory!\nExit!\n"); // spelling fix
       exit(0);
     }
     // use unsigned long long
     unsigned long long LI_d = 1;
     LI_d = (unsigned long long) -1;
     char *LI_b = decimal_to_binary(LI_d, 32);

     memset((*ptr_record).transmit, '\0', sizeof((*ptr_record).transmit));
     // strncat((*ptr_record).transmit, LI_b, strlen(LI_b));
     strncat((*ptr_record).transmit, LI_b, sizeof((*ptr_record).transmit) - 1);

     printf("LI: %s\n", (*ptr_record).transmit);

     //transmit and receive

     memset((*ptr_record).receive, '\0', sizeof((*ptr_record).receive));
     // strncpy((*ptr_record).receive, (*ptr_record).transmit, strlen((*ptr_record).transmit));
     strncpy((*ptr_record).receive, (*ptr_record).transmit, sizeof((*ptr_record).transmit) - 1);

     // char *LI_rcv_b = strndup((*ptr_record).receive, 64);
     char *LI_rcv_b = strndup((*ptr_record).receive, MAX_CHARACTERS);

     // At this point, approach is in error
     // Cannot take a 64-decimal digit string and convert to a typical long long.
     // int LI_rcv_i = atoi(LI_rcv_b);
     // int final_LI = binary_decimal(LI_rcv_i);
     // printf("Final_LI: %i\n", final_LI);

     // Suspect you want to convert 64-binary digit string to a 64-bit integer
     // maybe by somehow using binary_decimal - suggest re-write of that function
     unsigned long long LI_rcv_i = strtoull(LI_rcv_b, NULL, 2);
     printf("Final_LI: %llu\n", LI_rcv_i);

     free(ptr_record);
     return 0;
   }
   ```

Output

LI: 11111111111111111111111111111111
Final_LI: 4294967295